# "Please specify the product required option(s)." for downloadable products when adding them to cart programmatically

Tags: product, addtocart, downloadable, magento-1.9.2.1

I don't understand what might be going wrong, but even if I add "links" (downloadable product's links) to product's params, when I try to add it to cart I get the following error:

```
{"qty":1,"status":"ERROR","message":"Please specify the product required option(s)."}
```

I have installed Magento CE 1.9.2.1 version in my site.

Below is my code and effort to add downloadable product to cart programmatically:

```
public function addAction()
    {
        $cart = $this->_getCart();
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        Mage::log(print_r($params, true),NULL, 'developer.log');

        if(array_key_exists('prodType',$params) && $params['prodType'] == 'downloadable') {
        if ($params['isAjax'] == 1) {
            $response = array();
            try {
                if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                    $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(array(
                        'locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode()
                    ));
                    $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
                    $response['qty'] = $params['qty'];
                } else {
                    $response['qty'] = 1;
                }
                $product = $this->_initProduct();
                $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');
                /**
                 * Check product availability
                 */
                if (!$product) {
                    $response['status']  = 'ERROR';
                    $response['message'] = $this->__('Unable to find Product ID');
                }

                $links = Mage::getModel('downloadable/product_type')->getLinks( $product );
                ## echo "<pre/>";print_r($links);die;
                foreach ( $links as $link ):
                    if ( preg_match("/zip/i", $link->getLinkFile()) )
                        $linkId = $link->getLinkId();
                endforeach;

                $input = array( 'qty' => 1, 'links' => array( $linkId ) );
                $params = new Varien_Object();
                $params->setData($input);
                ## echo "<pre/>";print_r($params);die;

                $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                //if (!empty($related)) {
                    //$cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
                //}
                $cart->save();
                $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                $item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
                if ($item !== false) {
                    $response['cardId'] = $item->getId();
                } else {
                    $response['cardId'] = '';
                    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
                    foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
                        $response['cardId'] = $item->getId();
                        // Now you have a full loaded Product Object.
                    }
                }
                /**
                 * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
                 */
                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete', array(
                    'product' => $product,
                    'request' => $this->getRequest(),
                    'response' => $this->getResponse()
                ));
                if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                    $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($product->getName()));
                    $response['status']  = 'SUCCESS';
                    $response['message'] = $message;
                    //New Code Here
                    $this->loadLayout();
                    $toplink = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml();
                    $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('cart_sidebar');
                    Mage::register('referrer_url', $this->_getRefererUrl());
                    $sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
                    $response['toplink'] = $toplink;
                    $response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
                }
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $msg = "";
                if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    $msg = $e->getMessage();
                } else {
                    $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                    foreach ($messages as $message) {
                        $msg .= $message . '<br/>';
                    }
                }
                $response['status']  = 'ERROR';
                $response['message'] = $msg;
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $response['status']  = 'ERROR';
                $response['message'] = $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.');
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
            // print_r($response);
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
            return;
        } else {
            return parent::addAction();
        }
    } else {
        if ($params['isAjax'] == 1) {
            $response = array();
            try {
                if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                    $filter          = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(array(
                        'locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode()
                    ));
                    $params['qty']   = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
                    $response['qty'] = $params['qty'];
                } else {
                    $response['qty'] = 1;
                }
                $product = $this->_initProduct();
                $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');
                /**
                 * Check product availability
                 */
                if (!$product) {
                    $response['status']  = 'ERROR';
                    $response['message'] = $this->__('Unable to find Product ID');
                }
                $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                if (!empty($related)) {
                    $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
                }
                $cart->save();
                $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                $item  = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
                if ($item !== false) {
                    $response['cardId'] = $item->getId();
                } else {
                    $response['cardId'] = '';
                    $session            = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
                    foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
                        $response['cardId'] = $item->getId();
                        // Now you have a full loaded Product Object.
                    }
                }
                /**
                 * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
                 */
                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete', array(
                    'product' => $product,
                    'request' => $this->getRequest(),
                    'response' => $this->getResponse()
                ));
                if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                    $message             = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($product->getName()));
                    $response['status']  = 'SUCCESS';
                    $response['message'] = $message;
                    //New Code Here
                    $this->loadLayout();
                    $toplink       = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml();
                    $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('cart_sidebar');
                    Mage::register('referrer_url', $this->_getRefererUrl());
                    $sidebar             = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
                    $response['toplink'] = $toplink;
                    $response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
                }
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $msg = "";
                if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    $msg = $e->getMessage();
                } else {
                    $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                    foreach ($messages as $message) {
                        $msg .= $message . '<br/>';
                    }
                }
                $response['status']  = 'ERROR';
                $response['message'] = $msg;
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $response['status']  = 'ERROR';
                $response['message'] = $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.');
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
            // print_r($response);
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
            return;
        } else {
            return parent::addAction();
        }
    }
    }
```

Anybody please guide me and help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

In that product have required custom options values. When you are adding cart these custom options should be send in

```
$customOption = array(optionid1 => optionValue1, optionid2 => optionValue2);

$params = array('product' => $product_id,
                    'qty' => '1',
                    'options' => $customOption 
            );  

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($product_id);

$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
```

**Note:**  data value should be in that date format.

Comment: if u want to get option id dynamically **'$product->getOptions()'** in these values have the array of custom option values it has options, SKU, label, price everything. You can take option Id based on type and SKU.

Comment: For option types multiSelect, radio and dropdown the format of post params should be ** optionId[0] = OptionValue1; (radio and drop)  and optionId[0] = OptionValue1;  optionId[1] = OptionValue2; .. etc (multiSelect) **

Comment: Date Format optionId = array (
                    "month" => 9,
                    "day" => 8,
                    "year" => 2024)     Time Format optionId = array([hour] => 3
                    [minute] => 1
                    [day_part] => am)   if it is datetime jsut combain both format